# Primefaces p:selectManyCheckbox doesn't work with c:forEach and f:selectItem

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How to use these tags together as now they don't work:

```
<p:scrollPanel mode="native" style="height: 200px;">
    <p:selectManyCheckbox id="groups" value="#{myBean.selectedGroups}" layout="custom" >
        <c:forEach items="#{myBean.myGroups}" var="group" >
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{group.id}" itemLabel="#{group.name}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
</p:scrollPanel>
```

I want to do this to put each `<f:selectItem/>` inside of the `<li></li>` later.

Additional details: `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"`, PrimeFaces version 3.4.1.

Comment: Before asking usage questions about PrimeFaces components, always first check its showcase and documentation: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml

Comment: This showcase doesn't have a loop for `f:selectItem`. `f:selectItems` is not ok for me

Comment: So you still haven't carefully checked the mentioned version and actual source code in the showcase? The custom layout requires a minimum version and the individual checkbox items are not to be rendered the way as you expected.